# Amazon S3 - x-amz-meta

Tags: php, amazon-s3, metadata, amazon-web-services

I'm uploading photos, via PHP, to an Amazon S3 bucket. Everything is working great so far.

My question is about `x-amz-meta`. Would I use `x-amz-meta` key/value pairs to store data like the User ID of the person uploading and their account type (free, premium, etc.)? Or do I store this as regular metadata, not prefixed with `x-amz-meta`?

Currently sample metadata for a photo looks like:

```
Key: x-amz-meta-user-id      Value: 1
Key: x-amz-meta-user-type    Value: free
Key: Content-Type            Value: image/jpeg
```

Does that make sense? I hope so. Just checking I'm storing this metadata in the right way.

Thanks!

Jack

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Custom metadata values must use the `x-amz-meta-` prefix, like your examples:

```
Key: x-amz-meta-user-id      Value: 1
Key: x-amz-meta-user-type    Value: free
```

Comment: Thanks very much for confirming, Paul! :)

Comment: Thanks, @paul-k I confess I didn't read the docs (just jumped into the shell) but I had no idea why the S3 web-based console wasn't accepting my key/value pairs as it isn't clear that they require the `x-amz-meta-` prefix...

Comment: If you're getting errors when trying to set x-amz-meta, note that it only accepts strings. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044772/aws-s3-x-amz-meta-error-with-non-string-values-invalidheader-and-invalidparamet