# AWS S3 x-amz-meta error with non-string values: InvalidHeader and InvalidParameterType

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

When attempting to use the node.js AWS sdk `s3Client.upload` with optional parameters for metadata:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3Client = new AWS.S3({
  params: {
    Key: key,
    secret: secret
  }
})

let uploadParams = {
  Bucket: '',
  Key: '',
  Body: '',
  ACL: 'public-read',
  Metadata: {
    dummy_value: null
  }

s3Client.upload(uploadParams, function(err, data) {
  console.log('Upload: ', data)
}
```

Error is thrown:

> InvalidHeader: Header x-amz-meta-dummy_value contains invalid value

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the [AWS S3 SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) does not cover valid values for the input value of `x-amz-meta-` prepended metadata attributes.

`dummy_value` **must be a string**

Errors are thrown for:

- undefined // InvalidHeader: Header x-amz-meta-dummy_value contains
  invalid value
- null // InvalidHeader: Header x-amz-meta-dummy_value
  contains invalid value
- 12 // InvalidParameterType: Expected
  params.Metadata['dummy_value'] to be a string